# Oracle SQL: GROUP BY HAVING multiple criteria

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, having

I have the following query:

```
SELECT PERSON_ID 
FROM TABLE
WHERE YEAR > 2013
AND ACTION = 'TERM'
GROUP BY PERSON_ID
HAVING COUNT(ACTION) = 1
```

This query is returning PERSON_IDs with one `TERM` action among other actions.

How can I modify my `HAVING` clause to have the query return PERSON_IDs with one `TERM` action and no other actions? I tried moving the `AND ACTION = 'TERM'` below the `HAVING` line, but, as there is no `GROUP BY` operation in that line, I am getting an error.

Comment: Please show a [mcve]

Comment: Can `ACTION` be `null`? And if so, what is the desired result from the query - if a person has exactly two rows, one with `ACTION = 'TERM'` and the other with `ACTION = ''` (`null`), should that person be selected or not?

Answer (score 5):

Here is one method:

```
SELECT PERSON_ID 
FROM TABLE
WHERE YEAR > 2013
GROUP BY PERSON_ID
HAVING COUNT(ACTION) = 1 AND MIN(ACTION) = 'TERM'
```

Comment: Gordon = genius. Thank you.